# jQuery Flot and graphTable Colors

Tags: jquery, flot

How can I change the line colors with the *flot* plugin and *graphTable*:

```
$('table.statics').graphTable({series: 'columns', position : 
       'replace', height : '180px'});
```

But I would like to change the colors in the options of graphTable, something like:

```
$('table.statics').graphTable({series: 'columns', position : 
       'replace', height : '180px', 
       colors: ["#92d5ea", "#666699", "#be1e2d", "#ee8310", "#8d10ee"]});
```

And then each line in the resulting flot graph would have the corresponding colors from the column.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In flot you can specify the color for a particular series:

```
//series object
{
  data: rowData,
  label: label,
  color: '#92d5ea'
}
```

Looking through the graphTable plugin, there's a line like this twice:

```
tableData[tableData.length] = { label: label, data: rowData };
```

That's where it is creating the series object.  So you would have to figure out your color in that area and then set it.

**EDIT**:  If you want to be able to set it via the graphTable call, you'll have to edit the graphTable plugin and add a `colors` argument as a possibility.  Here's how:

```
//find the line after "var args = {" and add this
colors: null,
```

Then later, instead of

```
tableData[tableData.length] = { label: label, data: colData };
```

Put this:

```
var series = {label: label, data: colData };
if (args.colors && args.colors[j-args.dataStart]){
    series.color = args.colors[j-args.dataStart]
}
tableData[tableData.length] = series;
```

Note I am only showing how to deal with the columns section, not rows.  Now you can do something like this:

```
$('#table1').graphTable({series: 'columns', colors: ['red','red','blue']});
```

And the result looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ByyAT/) (doesn't work in IE due to no excanvas).

Comment: tableData[tableData.length] = { label: label, data: colData, color : '#000' }; is working only both lines become black then... Is there a way to make 1 line black and one grey or someting? :)

Comment: In that case, change `foo` to `$table.css('color')` and it will use the color defined by the table's css.

Comment: Same thing i have a screen of it: http://www.gallerion.nl/example.gif the color of the table is now red. I want 1 line red and 1 in black.
I hope you can help :)

Comment: Thnx Ryley, i gonna play with it in the morning! But it is not working in IE? :(

Comment: just my example doesn't work in IE because I don't include excanvas for flot

Comment: Hi Ryley it is working perfect, Thnx again. But i have a little question (again sorry) is it possible to give the lines colors with css? someting like `table.statics .line1 { color : #black; }`, `table.statics .line2 { color : #red; }` @Ryley

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ByyAT/2/  Remember, you can now construct that colors array using any jQuery or javascript you want...